# How to receive email notification of non-AD joined DHCP leases?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, powershell, dhcp, powershell-v4.0

This answer to theCleaner's question helped me some [Windows DHCP Server - get notification when a non-AD joined device gets an IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/550653/windows-dhcp-server-get-notification-when-a-non-ad-joined-device-gets-an-ip-ad) but the answer to his question involved Quest Poweshell cmdlets.  I would like to achieve a solution with plain old Powershell v4 cmdlets.

## Problem

I currently receive no notification of new DHCP leases at all.  I would like to receive notifications when someone plugs into one of our jacks here, gets a DHCP lease from our Windows Server 2012 DHCP server, but hasn't been AD-joined.  So I want an email notification of new DHCP leases for non-AD joined devices.

## What I've tried

I have put together some Powershell code, borrowing some from theCleaner's question mentioned above.

```
 Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -allleases -ScopeId #myscopeIDhere | Select-Object @{expression= {$_.hostname}; label='name' } | export-CSV -notypeinformation C:\dhcp\LeaseLog.csv

import-module activedirectory

#get input CSV

$leaselogpath = "c:\DHCP\LeaseLog.csv"
Import-csv -path $leaselogpath | 
#query AD for computer name based on csv log
foreach-object `
{ 
   $NameResult = Get-ADComputer -Filter * 
   If ($NameResult -eq $null) {$RogueSystem = $_.name}
   $RogueSystem | Out-File C:\DHCP\RogueClients.txt -Append
   $RogueSystem = $null

}
Get-Content C:\DHCP\RogueClients.txt | Select-Object -Unique | Out-File C:\DHCP\RogueClientsFinal.txt
Remove-Item C:\DHCP\RogueClients.txt

#send email to sysadmin
$smtpserver = #my email server IP address here
$from="abcd@abcdefg.com"
$to="sysadmin@abcdefg.com"
$subject="Non-AD joined DHCP clients"
$body= (Get-Content C:\DHCP\RogueClientsFinal.txt) -join '<BR>&nbsp;<BR>'
$mailer = new-object Net.Mail.SMTPclient($smtpserver)
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from,$to,$subject,$body)
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$mailer.send($msg)
```

I receive the email "Non-AD joined DHCP clients" but there are no objects in the email.  We do have non-AD joined DHCP leases (I connected a non-AD laptop the network for testing), but the laptop doesn't show in the email.  I don't receive any red test after running the script either.

If anyone has suggestions please let me know.  I obviously have something wrong somewhere in my script.  I personally think it might have to do with my AD cmdlets and the CSV import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$NameResult = Get-ADComputer -Filter *
```

This query will return ***all computers in AD***, and its result will never be empty; you should query for the actual computer name you are trying to find:

```
$NameResult = Get-ADComputer $_.Name
```

Also, the names in the DHCP log files will likely be FQDNs (such as `computer.domain.local`); if this is the case, you need to strip the domain suffix before feeding them into [Get-ADcomputer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx), which only wants the computer name:

```
$ComputerName = $_.Name.Replace(".domain.local",$null)
$Result = Get-ADComputer $ComputerName
```

Comment: I had tried $NameResult = Get-ADComputer $_.Name before, but that didn't work; I was emailed the entire DHCP lease list, even AD-joined leases so that is why I tried filtering against the computer objects in AD.  What worked is eliminating $NameResult = Get-ADComputer $_.Name from my script and in its place using your $ComputerName = $_.Name.Replace(".domain.local",$null)
$Result = Get-ADComputer $ComputerName 
Thank you so much.  It makes sense too.  After reading your answer I definitely had a "DOH!" moment and thought, "Of course!"